# How to display table from MySQL database in Windows Form Textbox

Tags: c#, mysql, database, winforms

I'm creating an application that displays a table of data (id, name, age, castle) when you press a button. I'm not sure how to make it display the table into a textbox after clicking the button.

Here is a display of the Windows Form: http://puu.sh/lPSi6/204b0d15c0.png

Once the button "Get People From Selected Castle" is pressed I want it to display the table into the textbox.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data.Common;

namespace DatabaseApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private static DbConnection CreateMySQLConnection()
        {
            String connectionString = "id=csuperson;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=westeros;allowuservariables=True";

            DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("MySql.Data.MySqlClient");
            DbConnection conn = factory.CreateConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = connectionString;
            return conn;
        }

        private static void PrintPeopleByCastle(DbConnection conn, String castleValue)
        {
            DbCommand mycmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            String mySqlStmt = "select* from  person";

            if (castleValue != "all") mySqlStmt += " where castle='" + castleValue + "'";
            mycmd.CommandText = mySqlStmt;
            mycmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

            DbDataReader dataReader = mycmd.ExecuteReader();
            Console.WriteLine("\n Executing: " + mySqlStmt);

            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(dataReader[0].ToString().PadRight(5)
                    + dataReader[1].ToString().PadRight(20)
                    + dataReader[2].ToString().PadRight(5)
                    + dataReader[3].ToString().PadRight(20));
            }
            dataReader.Close();
        }

        private static void UpdatePeople (DbConnection conn)
        {
            DbCommand mycmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            mycmd.CommandText = "update person set age = (age+1) where castle = 'WINTERFELL'";
            mycmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

            int recordsAffected = mycmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Console.WriteLine("\nRecords affected (see age)... " + recordsAffected);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        private void getPeopleButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          try
            {
                DbConnection conn = CreateMySQLConnection();
                conn.Open();
                PrintPeopleByCastle(conn, "all");
                conn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception x)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR: " + x.Message);
            }
            Console.Read();
        }

        private void youngerButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void olderButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

My SQL Script is:

```
CREATE DATABASE westeros;

CREATE TABLE `westeros`.`person` (
 `id` INT NOT NULL,
 `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
 `age` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
 `castle` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`));

INSERT INTO `westeros`.`person` (`id`, `name`, `age`, `castle`) VALUES ('100', 'Arya
Stark', '12', 'Winterfell');
INSERT INTO `westeros`.`person` (`id`, `name`, `age`, `castle`) VALUES ('200',
'Daenerys Targaryen', '20', 'Dragonstone');
INSERT INTO `westeros`.`person` (`id`, `name`, `age`, `castle`) VALUES ('300',
'Cersei Baratheon', '35', 'KingsLanding');
INSERT INTO `westeros`.`person` (`id`, `name`, `age`, `castle`) VALUES ('400',
'Tiryon Lannister', '32', 'KingsLanding');
INSERT INTO `westeros`.`person` (`id`, `name`, `age`, `castle`) VALUES ('500', 'Jon
Snow', '21', 'Winterfell');
```

http://puu.sh/lPSCc/6034433a44.png

Comment: DbConnection should throw an exception if you're unable to open.  Check the nested exceptions if needed to find out why the provider wasn't able to open the connection.  (ie. bad credentials, host not found, etc)

Comment: is there a gui component you want this in to go in, in particular? I don't see how a text box has much to do with this (even if multi-line)